# Plotly with datetime.time() in the x-axis and missing values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, plotly

I have 2 pandas dataframes, df1 and df2 which both have data from 2 different days between 21:00 and 8:00. The data should be 1 data point per minute, however there are there are missing values e.g.

```
       location        time             Data
0          1         21:00:00            8
1          1         21:02:00            6
```

the data point for 21:01:00 does not exist.
The missing data points occur at different times for each of the dataframes, so when I try to plot both of them on the same plot this happens:
[image]

If I plot them individually they're both correct. I think the horizontal red lines are caused by the time values that exist in the red dataframe but not in the blue dataframe.

Has anyone encountered this before? I want to plot both of them on the same axis, starting at 21:00 and finishing at 08:00.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'location': 1,
                    'data': ['3', '4', '5'], 
                   'time': [datetime.datetime(2022,7,16,21,0,0).time(), 
                            datetime.datetime(2022,7,16,21,1,0).time(), 
                            datetime.datetime(2022,7,16,21,3,0).time()]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'location': 2,
                    'data': ['8', '6', '7'], 
                   'time': [datetime.datetime(2022,7,17,21,0,0).time(), 
                            datetime.datetime(2022,7,17,21,2,0).time(), 
                            datetime.datetime(2022,7,17,21,3,0).time()]})

df = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=0)

fig = px.line(df, x="time", y="data", color='location')
fig.show()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- started by simulating data that has the features you describe.  From 21:00 to 08:00 on different dates and with different randomly removed minutes
- now integrate this data.  Have taken approach

  1. fill missing *minutes* by outer join to all minutes in each dataframe
  2. outer join the two data frames on **time** only

This gives a different struct data frame:

|  | location_x | time_x | Data_x | t | location_y | time_y | Data_y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2022-09-01 21:00:00 | 0 | 21:00:00 | 2 | 2022-09-04 21:00:00 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2022-09-01 21:01:00 | 0.0302984 | 21:01:00 | 2 | 2022-09-04 21:01:00 | 0.999541 |
| 2 | 1 | 2022-09-01 21:02:00 | 0.060569 | 21:02:00 | 2 | 2022-09-04 21:02:00 | 0.998164 |
| 3 | 1 | 2022-09-01 21:03:00 | 0.0907839 | 21:03:00 | 2 | 2022-09-04 21:03:00 | 0.995871 |
| 4 | 1 | 2022-09-01 21:04:00 | 0.120916 | 21:04:00 | 2 | 2022-09-04 21:04:00 | nan |

This is then simple to generate a `px.line()` figure from.  Traces being **Data_x** and **Data_y**.  Have used *datetime* column **time_x** for **xaxis**.   This then works well as datetime and continuous axes are well integrated.  Updated `tickformat` so date part of axis is not displayed.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

dr = pd.date_range("2022-09-01 21:00", "2022-09-02 08:00", freq="1Min")

# data to match question, two dataframes from 21:00 to 08:00, different dates with some holes
# with different dates
dfs = [
    pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "location": np.full(len(dr), l),
            "time": dr + pd.DateOffset(days=o),
            "Data": f(np.linspace(0, 20, len(dr))),
        }
    )
    .sample(frac=0.95)
    .sort_index()
    for l, o, f in zip([1, 2], [0, 3], [np.sin, np.cos])
]


df1 = dfs[0]
df2 = dfs[1]

# let's integrate the dataframes
# 1. fill the holes in each dataframe by doing an outer join to all times
# 2. outer join the two dataframes on just the time
df = pd.merge(
    *[
        pd.merge(
            d,
            pd.DataFrame(
                {"time": pd.date_range(d["time"].min(), d["time"].max(), freq="1min")}
            ),
            on="time",
            how="outer",
        )
        .fillna({"location": l})
        .assign(t=lambda d: d["time"].dt.time)
        for d, l in zip([df1, df2], [1, 2])
    ],
    on="t",
    how="outer",
)


# finally generate plotly line chart using columns created by merging the data
# it's clearly observed there are gaps in both traces
px.line(
    df.sort_values("time_x"), x="time_x", y=["Data_x", "Data_y"], hover_data=["time_y"]
).update_layout({"xaxis": {"tickformat": "%H:%M"}})
```

#### output

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this works. I tried to merge on the time object earlier but I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the time column. As you convert it to `time()`, this will be converted to object when you combine the dataframes. Check `df.info()`. To avoid this, leave the data in datetime format and use `update_axis()` to let `px` set the time. Updated code below...

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'location': 1,
                    'data': ['3', '4', '5'], 
                   'time': [datetime.datetime(2022,7,16,21,0,0), 
                            datetime.datetime(2022,7,16,21,1,0), 
                            datetime.datetime(2022,7,16,21,3,0)]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'location': 2,
                    'data': ['8', '6', '7'], 
                   'time': [datetime.datetime(2022,7,16,21,0,0), 
                            datetime.datetime(2022,7,16,21,2,0), 
                            datetime.datetime(2022,7,16,21,3,0)]})

df = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=0)

fig = px.line(df, x="time", y="data", color='location')
fig.update_xaxes(tickformat="%H:%M:%S")
fig.show()
```

**Plot**

[image]

**EDIT**

As per your updated requirement, you want to remove the date section and show ONLY time, without caring for the date. To do this, you can go back to taking only the `time()` in your dataframe creation. Post concatenation of the dfs, use a dummy date (2022-01-01 here) and create the datetime and plot. This will give you below graph.

```
## Note that you need to use .time()
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'location': 1, 'data': ['3', '4', '5'], 
                   'time': [datetime.datetime(2022,7,17,21,0,0).time(), 
                            datetime.datetime(2022,7,17,21,1,0).time(), 
                            datetime.datetime(2022,7,17,21,3,0).time()]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'location': 2, 'data': ['8', '6', '7'], 
                   'time': [datetime.datetime(2022,7,16,21,0,0).time(), 
                            datetime.datetime(2022,7,16,21,2,0).time(), 
                            datetime.datetime(2022,7,16,21,3,0).time()]})

df = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=0)
date = str(datetime.datetime.strptime('2022-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d').date())  ##Random dummy date
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(date + " " + df['time'].astype(str)) ##Convert back to datetime
fig = px.line(df, x="time", y="data", color='location')
fig.update_xaxes(tickformat="%H:%M")
fig.show()
```

[image]

Now, for the second part of your requirement - the graph needs to always show 9PM to 8AM. To do this, you will need to use the `range_x` with the start and end times. Replace above `px.line()` with these lines...

```
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime('2022-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d')
starttime = dt.replace(hour=21, minute=0) ## Start time is 9PM
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime('2022-01-02', '%Y-%m-%d')
endtime = dt.replace(hour=8, minute=0) ## End time is 8AM next day
fig = px.line(df, x="time", y="data", color='location', range_x=[starttime, endtime])
```

[image]

Please note that I have shown both plots to showcase that, if you take a longer period (9 to 8), the lines will just look like vertical lines. Hope you are okay with that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the problem with this is that the times are from 2 different dates so when I do as you suggested they're not plotted one over the other. There's a big space in the middle.

Comment: I have updated the df2 definition, to change the datetime values to the 17th to illustrate what I mean, apologies I'd missed that earlier.

Comment: Hi Agustin - Ok... in that case, do you want to plot them in separate plots - maybe using [make_subplots()](https://plotly.com/python/subplots/). Else, what is the expectation? How would you want the two plots?

Comment: I want the plot to look like the one you posted. However the datetime values as from different dates (they're not created manually as in the example but come from another source). 
I want the values for the x-axis to be just the time component of the datetime object, ignoring the date. But starting at 21:00 and ending at 8:00

Comment: Pls check updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help @Redox it was very helpful but unfortunately doesn't work as I want it to when using the full datasets.
This is the result for the equivalent of this:

```
## Note that you need to use .time()
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'location': 1, 'data': ['3', '4', '5'], 
                   'time': [datetime.datetime(2022,7,17,21,0,0).time(), 
                            datetime.datetime(2022,7,17,21,1,0).time(), 
                            datetime.datetime(2022,7,17,21,3,0).time()]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'location': 2, 'data': ['8', '6', '7'], 
                   'time': [datetime.datetime(2022,7,16,21,0,0).time(), 
                            datetime.datetime(2022,7,16,21,2,0).time(), 
                            datetime.datetime(2022,7,16,21,3,0).time()]})

df = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=0)
date = str(datetime.datetime.strptime('2022-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d').date())  ##Random dummy date
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(date + " " + df['time'].astype(str)) ##Convert back to datetime
fig = px.line(df, x="time", y="data", color='location')
fig.update_xaxes(tickformat="%H:%M")
fig.show()
```

[image]

When I try this:

```
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime('2022-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d')
starttime = dt.replace(hour=21, minute=0) ## Start time is 9PM
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime('2022-01-02', '%Y-%m-%d')
endtime = dt.replace(hour=8, minute=0) ## End time is 8AM next day
fig = px.line(df, x="time", y="data", color='location', range_x=[starttime, endtime])
```

This is the result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me eventually:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'location': 1, 'data': ['3', '4', '5'], 
                       'time_num': [datetime.datetime(2022,7,17,21,0,0).time().hour + datetime.datetime(2022,7,17,21,0,0).time().minute/60, 
                                datetime.datetime(2022,7,17,21,1,0).time().hour + datetime.datetime(2022,7,17,21,0,0).time().minute/60,  
                                datetime.datetime(2022,7,17,21,3,0).time().hour + datetime.datetime(2022,7,17,21,0,0).time().minute/60, ]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'location': 2, 'data': ['8', '6', '7'], 
                       'time_num': [datetime.datetime(2022,7,16,21,0,0).time().hour + datetime.datetime(2022,7,16,21,0,0).time().minute/60, 
                                datetime.datetime(2022,7,16,21,2,0).time().hour + datetime.datetime(2022,7,16,21,2,0).time().minute/60, 
                                datetime.datetime(2022,7,16,21,3,0).time().hour + datetime.datetime(2022,7,16,21,3,0).time().minute/60]})
    
df_skeleton = pd.DataFrame()
df_skeleton['date'] = pd.date_range(datetime.datetime(2022,7,16,20,0,0), datetime.datetime(2022,7,17,8,0,0), freq = '1min')
df_skeleton['time']=df_test['date'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
df_skeleton['hour']=df_test['date'].dt.strftime('%H')
df_skeleton['min']=df_test['date'].dt.strftime('%M')
df_skeleton[['hour', 'min']] = df_test[['hour', 'min']].astype(int)
df_skeleton['time_num'] = df_test['hour'] + df_test['min']/60

result_1 = pd.merge(df_skeleton, df1, how="left", on=["time_num", "time_num"])
result_2 = pd.merge(df_skeleton, df2, how="left", on=["time_num", "time_num"])
result_1['location'] = '1'
fig = px.line(result_1, x='time', y='data',color='location')
fig.add_scatter(x=result_2['time'], y=result_2['data'],mode='lines', name='2')
fig.update_traces(connectgaps=True)
fig.show()
```

I'm not overly pleased with it but it works both with the dummy dataframes and the full dataframes.
[image]
[image]