# Python Plotly - using datetime on x-axis, how to plot one trace for each day in dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, plotly

I have a dataframe that has data for the past 7 days. It consists of columns ['datetime', 'value']. Data is in general 5 minutes apart, but that is not always the case, and there are sometimes missing data points.

**I am trying to plot each day for the past 7 days on one chart**. Each day should have its own trace and legend label.

I have gotten close to what I want by using the following code. It creates separate dataframes for each day, then adds a new trace with a hidden separate x-axis. I use "overlaying='x'" to ensure that the traces are overlaid.

```
# Extract date and time components
df['date'] = df['datetime'].dt.date
df['time'] = df['datetime'].dt.time

# Create a dictionary to store DataFrames
date_dataframes = {}

# Iterate over unique dates and create new DataFrames
for date in df['date'].unique():
    filtered_data = df[df['date'] == date]
    date_dataframes[date] = filtered_data

fig = go.Figure()

x_axes = ['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4', 'x5', 'x6', 'x7']
xaxis_counter = 0

for date in df['date'].unique():

    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=date_dataframes[date]['time'],
                             y=date_dataframes[date]['bgl'],
                             name=str(date),
                             xaxis=x_axes[xaxis_counter]))
    xaxis_counter += 1

fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(
                     domain=[0, 1],
                     range=[0, 288]
                     ),
                  xaxis2=dict(
                      domain=[0, 1],
                      overlaying='x',
                      showticklabels=False
                      ),
                  xaxis3=dict(
                      domain=[0, 1],
                      overlaying='x',
                      showticklabels=False
                      ),
                  xaxis4=dict(
                      domain=[0, 1],
                      overlaying='x',
                      showticklabels=False
                      ),
                  xaxis5=dict(
                      domain=[0, 1],
                      overlaying='x',
                      showticklabels=False
                      ),
                  xaxis6=dict(
                      domain=[0, 1],
                      overlaying='x',
                      showticklabels=False
                      ),
                  xaxis7=dict(
                      domain=[0, 1],
                      overlaying='x',
                      showticklabels=False
                      )
            )

fig.update_layout(template='simple_white')

fig.update_yaxes(title_text='value (units)')

fig.show()
```

Output:
[image]

**The problem is that the chart is plotting by using an x-axis that is spaced by the # of data points rather than the actual time that the datapoint occurred.** For example, in the above image, you can see that the x-axis label reads "16:12" but the timestamps for each of the traces, upon hover, are all over the place. This is because some data is missing, and/or the timing between the datapoints is not exactly 5 minutes.

**How can I plot these so that they are time-aligned, so that the chart x-axis ranges from 12AM to 12AM exactly?** Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated!!

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73618928/plotly-with-datetime-time-in-the-x-axis-and-missing-values) Is close to my problem but none of the solutions work for me. The accepted answer only deals with merging two dataframes, and I have seven that I am not sure how to merge in that way.

Here is some code to create an example df:

```
import pandas as pd
import random
from datetime import timedelta, datetime

# Set the start date and time
start_date = datetime.now()
end_date = start_date + timedelta(days=7)

# Generate datetime values at 5-minute intervals
date_range = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq='5min')

# Generate values with a difference no more than 20
values = []
previous_value = random.randint(60, 200)
for _ in range(len(date_range)):
    values.append(previous_value)
    previous_value = random.randint(max(previous_value - 20, 60), min(previous_value + 20, 200))

# Create the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'datetime': date_range, 'values': values})

# Print the dataframe
print(df)
```